# .NET MAUI Push Notifications with Firebase Cloud Mesaging

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I want to implement a very simple push notification system using Firebase Cloud Messaging.

The MAUI project is built on top of the .NET 8 version.

I've followed [this](https://cedricgabrang.medium.com/firebase-push-notifications-in-net-maui-android-32c808844d7e) guide for setting the project up.

Where guide used .net6 I replaced with .net8

So my .csproj file looks like this :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;</TargetFrameworks>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>PushNotificationsTest</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>PushNotificationsTest</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.companyname.pushnotificationstest</ApplicationId>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0-android'">
        <GoogleServicesJson Include="google-services.json" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0-rc.1.23419.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Firebase" Version="2.0.7" />
        <PackageReference Include="Plugin.FirebaseCrashlytics" Version="4.1.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- Build Properties must be defined within these property groups to ensure successful publishing
       to the Mac App Store. See: https://aka.ms/maui-publish-app-store#define-build-properties-in-your-project-file -->
    <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-maccatalyst')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
        <CodesignEntitlements>Platforms/MacCatalyst/Entitlements.Debug.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-maccatalyst')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
        <CodesignEntitlements>Platforms/MacCatalyst/Entitlements.Release.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
        <UseHardenedRuntime>true</UseHardenedRuntime>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

But when I want to run the application I get the following exception :

```
Error JAVA0000 java.exe: Error in C:\Users\mdavidovic\.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm\1.3.0.1\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\..\..\jar\androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArraySetKt.class:
Type androidx.collection.ArraySetKt is defined multiple times: C:\Users\mdavidovic\.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm\1.3.0.1\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\..\..\jar\androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArraySetKt.class, C:\Users\mdavidovic\.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.ktx\1.2.0.9\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\..\..\jar\androidx.collection.collection-ktx.jar:androidx/collection/ArraySetKt.class
Compilation failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: C:\Users\mdavidovic\.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm\1.3.0.1\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\..\..\jar\androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar
androidx/collection/ArraySetKt.class
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:126)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.main(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:5)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: C:\Users\mdavidovic\.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm\1.3.0.1\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\..\..\jar\androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArraySetKt.class
    at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_8.1.56.java:0)
    at com.android.tools.r8.M.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:5)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:81)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:32)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:31)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.b(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:2)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:26)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:13)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:24)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:113)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Type androidx.collection.ArraySetKt is defined multiple times: C:\Users\mdavidovic\.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm\1.3.0.1\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\..\..\jar\androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArraySetKt.class, C:\Users\mdavidovic\.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.ktx\1.2.0.9\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\..\..\jar\androidx.collection.collection-ktx.jar:androidx/collection/ArraySetKt.class
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.O2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:21)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.O2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:26)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.A2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:44)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.A2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:10)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.merge(ConcurrentHashMap.java:2048)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.A2.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:6)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.b4$a.e(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:7)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.c.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:58)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.c.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:9)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.c.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:8)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:29)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:17)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.c(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(R8_8.1.56_756d1f50f618dd1c39c000f11defb367a21e9e866e3401b884be16c0950f6f79:28)
    ... 6 more

0>------- Finished building project: PushNotificationsTest. Succeeded: False. Errors: 1. Warnings: 3
```

I've been searching for a solution but I haven't seen anyone to use MAUI with .NET 8 for push notifications.

Could anyone help me ?

Thanks in forward !

I removed this piece of code from the .csproj file because the error is the same with or without it :

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0-android'">
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib.Jdk7" Version="1.7.10" ExcludeAssets="build;buildTransitive" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib.Jdk8" Version="1.7.10" ExcludeAssets="build;buildTransitive" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I tried deleting bin and obj folders and cleaning the whole solution, but nothing seemed to help.

I've also tried to follow this answer over [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/18665) by @moljac, installing "Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment.Ktx" nuget package, but the error was the same...

Comment: This might be similar to the issues we've been hitting trying to get firebase working in .net7, there is something that is defined in two different packages that you need and they are clashing. I have not seen a single working firebase example for .net 7, and I don't have high hopes this will be resolved for .net 8 anytime soon :(

Comment: You can try to clean the whole solution, then restart VS (this is important). If you still have the problem, you can try closing VS then delete all bin and obj folders then run a dotnet restore before starting VS and build again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this exact problem just a couple of days ago, albeit with a differnt .net version.

I'm trying to recall how I resolved it, I think it was by adding these two package references;

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Preference" Version="1.2.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.Android.Material" Version="1.10.0.1" />
```

You might have to clean before you rebuild as well.

Comment: Thank you, dude, this resolved the issue. 
The main thing is that I have to put both of them into ItemGroup where the GoogleServiceJson is located, otherwise it complains about the version saying that both packages are not compatible with.NET 8 even after clean and rebuild.

Comment: faced same error with .NET 7. this fix saves my day, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i thing your condition for implement this packages :

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0-android'">
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib.Jdk7" Version="1.7.10" ExcludeAssets="build;buildTransitive" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib.Jdk8" Version="1.7.10" ExcludeAssets="build;buildTransitive" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**Target net6.0-android** , and you are on net8.0-android

but maybe it' will don't work because net8 is newer ?

Comment: If you're unsure in your answer, you should get clarity through comments rather than speculating.