# Maui Project can't deploy on net7-ios when i add Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, maui

[image]

Hello,

i can't deploy my project after installing  Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging and i have actually no idea why ,

i have already my googleService-Info.plist defined

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net7.0-ios'">
    <BundleResource Include="Platforms\iOS\GoogleService-Info.plist" />
</ItemGroup>
```

i tried before to use plugin.Firebase for my maui project but after a lot of problems for use it , i decided to come back with old xamarin project package because i have little time (so Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging for Ios)

i have already resolve the problem of long path from the ios cloud package with override NUGGET-PACKAGES  (env PATH) to my new directory of nugget (C:\Nuget)

someone have an idea or can help me?

Comment: The reason is that the [Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging/#supportedframeworks-body-tab) only supports `net6.0-ios15.4`, you are deploying it on .net 7 ios, it failed.

Comment: Thanks for this response, dotnet 7 don't work so i will try net 8

Comment: still don't work with net 8 ,

but i need net 7 framework minimum for my project :/

Comment: Since it doesn't support .net 7, it wouldn't support .net 8 either. If you want to target net 7 framework minimum, consider using [Plugin.Firebase](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Firebase/).

Comment: when i try plugin.firebase, I have this issue with net7: 

Type androidx.collection.ArraySetKt is defined multiple times:

and i don't find any solution that work in internet :/

Comment: Have you installed other packages? Can you try to manually delete the bin and obj folders to see if it works? Also, can you try this [workaround](https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/issues/800#issuecomment-1774562211)?

Comment: i have already try this workaround but didn't work for me

Comment: Thanks for the response, can you refer to this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77487528/net-maui-push-notifications-with-firebase-cloud-mesaging